# Looping though json object in html using jinja2

Tags: python, html, json, flask, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries called `dics`. I applied below transformation:

```
res= json.dumps({"dics": dics})
data = json.loads(res)
```

and use flask like this

```
return  render_template( "index.html" ,  data = data  )
```

Now in the `index.html` when I add `{{ data }}` I got a dictionary that its value is a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{'data': [{'video_id': '-44FZRHVPnA', 'start_time': 71.28}, {'video_id': '--1vgrmep6k', 'start_time': 7792.0}, {'video_id': '--1vgrmep6k', 'start_time': 4489.84}, {'video_id': '_-Jm3tE3GTE', 'start_time': 245.36}, {'video_id': '--1vgrmep6k', 'start_time': 4282.719}]}
```

I want **to loop through `{{ data }}` in HTML to get the dictionaries in the list** I tried things like

`{{data}}['data'][0]['video_id']`

and some variations to access the `{{ data }}` and always gives me data is not defined if i tried any thing except `{{ data }}`.

Comment: You need to be within the Jinja brackets to access what's inside your variable i.e. `{{ data['data'][0]['video_id'] }}`

Comment: Also, from your description there doesn't appear to be a need to pass your data through `json.dumps` then `json.loads`. You can just pass your list of dicts straight into `render_template()` and save a bit of computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your dictionary like this:

```
{%for record in data%}
<p>{{record.video_id}} {{record.start_time}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: When i add iframe tag to show the video it works well but starting the video at a specific time is not working correctly   
` {%for record in data%}
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{record.video_id}}?start{{record.start_time}}">
</iframe>

{%endfor%}`

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with the updated code, updated question tags and various error logs to make it easier to understand what the problem is.